# Getting random die face, using angles, without pole bias

Tags: probability-distributions, spherical-geometry

In the game Tabletop Simulator, I have created something which, rather than rolling a die, is design to just pick a random angle and place it down on the surface using Lua. My method for this is to set the X/Y/Z of the rotation to "random" numbers between 1 and 360.

However, someone pointed out that "using three uniformly distributed Euler angles is not sufficient for a uniform distribution of results". That the poles will be biased. Here is an example he shared: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

I ran automated simulations of thousands of rolls, and sure enough, [2 and 5 were heavily biased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y78H2.jpg). There has to be a mathematical solution, but I lack the knowledge to figure it out for myself. Any help is appreciated.

My original solution was:

```
x= math.random()*360    <-- random number between 0 and 360
y= math.random()*360
z= math.random()*360
```

This is my current attempt, which is also failing but in new and exciting ways:

```
u1 = math.random()
u2 = math.random()
u3 = math.random()
u4 = math.random()
    --w/x/y/z from your example
q0 = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(u1)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * u2)
q1 = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(u1)) * math.sin(2 * math.pi * u2)
q2 = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(u3)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * u4)
q3 = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(u3)) * math.sin(2 * math.pi * u4)
    --My conversion from w/x/y/z to Euler x/y/z
xr = math.atan(  (2*(q0*q1+q2*q3)) / (1-2*(q1^2+q2^2))  )
yr = math.asin(  2*(q0*q2 - q3*q1)  )
zr = math.atan(  (2*(q0*q3+q1*q2)) / (1-2*(q2^2+q3^2)) 
    --Converting radians to degrees to set the rotation
rotation = {math.deg(xr), math.deg(yr), math.deg(zr)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Gaussian distribution to obtain each Cartesian coordinate. It turns out that the product of Gaussian distributions is just a higher-dimensional Gaussian distribution, so the result will have no biases.

For example, in Java:

Random rand = new Random();

double x = rand.nextGaussian();

double y = rand.nextGaussian();

double z = rand.nextGaussian();

double theta = Math.atan(y / x);

double phi = Math.atan(z / Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y));

Now theta and phi together specify a direction. Note that you require only two angles, not three, to specify a direction in three-dimensional space.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to write a gaussian distribution for this purpose? It would need to end between 0 and 360. I've tried looking it up but my maths are too lacking to parse it together for this purpose.

Comment: You misunderstand; don't use a Gaussian distribution for the angle, use it for x, y, and z. I don't know the language you're using, but in Java I'd write something like "Random rand = new Random(); double x = rand.nextGaussian(); double y = rand.nextGaussian(); double z = rand.nextGaussian();". This defines a point in (x,y,z) coordinates. Convert it into spherical coordinates and you'll have your angles.

Comment: Actually I think what is wanted is not a point, but rather a matrix in $SO(3)$, so there's an additional degree of freedom (corresponding to a rotation around an axis in the direction of your point).